# How do I create templates for linking to PubMed Central ids and and DOI names in MediaWiki?

Tags: links, mediawiki, template

I want to build templates that would render `{{PMC|PMC number}}` as a PMC number.  That is, hyperlinked to the respective PubMed Central entry for said number. For example, `{{PMC|2824929}}` would be rendered as [PMC 2824929](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2824929/).

For DOI names, it's pretty much the same deal (i.e., I write `{{doi|doi number}}`) but it comes out as the DOI number hyperlinked to the respective dx.doi.org entry. For example, `{{doi|10.4103/0972-2327.56312}}` would be rendered as: [doi:10.4103/0972-2327.56312](http://dx.doi.org/10.4103/0972-2327.56312).

Answer (score 2):

You would write the following in `Template:PMC`:

```
[http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC{{{1}}}/ PMC {{{1}}}]
```

And then call it with `{{PMC|2824929}}`.

Of course this doesn't  verify that the number is valid or even that one has been provided.

Comment: If you want an entry point for a more advanced version of the template then [Template:doi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Doi) on English Wikipedia is probably a good start.